# What is the difference between these two code samples?

Tags: javascript

Code 1:

```
var Something = {
name: "Name",
  sayHi: function(){
     alert(Something.name);
  }
}
```

Code 2:

```
 function Something(){
    this.name = "Name";
 }

 Something.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    alert(Something.name);
 }
```

**Edit:**
So, Guys, you mean the Second one is better? or more "formal" ?

Comment: This is also a good question for me, thanks for posting.

Comment: In regards to your question in the edit, it depends on what you want to do. If you only have one copy of the object, go for the first syntax. If want to create multiple copies (like if `Something` was a `Class` in other languages), go for the second syntax (or actually, an edited version in which you define `sayHi` inside the constructor using `this.sayHi = function() { ... }`, this is the norm).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically in the first example you declare an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals#Object_Literals) which is actually already an object instance.

In your second example, you define a constructor function which can be used with the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/new_Operator) operator to create object instances.

Object literals can be also used to create new instances of objects and do prototypal inheritance, Douglas Crockford promotes also this technique.

Basically you can have an `object` operator:

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}
```

This helper function can be used in a very intuitive and convenient way.

It basically receive an object as a parameter, inside the function a *new object instance* is created, the old object is *chained* to the new object's prototype, and its returned.

It can be used like this:

```
var oldObject = {
  firstMethod: function () { alert('first'); },
  secondMethod: function () { alert('second'); },
};

var newObject = object(oldObject);
newObject.thirdMethod = function () { alert('third'); };

var otherObject = object(newObject);
otherObject.firstMethod();
```

You can go further as you want, making new instances from the previously defined objects.

Recommended :

- [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)
- [Advanced JavaScript (Video)](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111585)

Comment: Using `Object(Something)` is not the same as using the `new` keyword. In particular, if you change any property in the first case, it will be changed globally. For example `Object(Something).name = "new name"` changes it for Something itself, while `(new Something()).name = "new name"` only changes it for that particular _instance_.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was thinking about the `object` operator described in this article... http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score 7):

In the **first** code snippet, `Something` is a simple object, and not a constructor. In particular, you cannot call:

```
var o = new Something();
```

Such a form of creating objects is perfect for singletons; objects of which you only need one instance.

In the **second** snippet, `Something` is a constructor, and you can use the `new` keyword with it.

**Edit:**

Also, in your second snippet, since you are using `Something.name` as opposed to `this.name`, it will always alert the name of the constructor itself, which is *"Something"*, unless you override that property with something like `Something.name = "Cool";`.

You probably wanted that line to say:

```
alert(this.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

In first example you can do

```
Something.sayHi();
```

while in the second one you have to do it

```
new Something().sayHi();
```